Add mender to a Yocto (kirkstone) build to an Axon-Wizard IMX8mp
I want to add Mender to a Yocto (kirkstone) build. I'm using an Axon-Wizard IMX8mp. I found in the mender community a very similar board: Toradex Verdin IMX8mp. I tried to modify it but I was not able to make a successful build. I'm new to Yocto and Mender. So I'm unsure what I need in order to make it work. I found this post for the Toradex Verdin, explaining how to do it but I was not successful.
